# The Sitecore CDP JavaScript library is not loading on my site why?

Tags: personalization, cdp, sitecore-personalize

I'm trying to load the Sitecore CDP JavaScript library but I keep getting HTTP 403 forbidden. What is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have followed the steps outlined in the documentation for loading the JavaScript Library: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/javascript-tagging-examples-for-web-pages.html and the JavaScript Library is not loading as expected this could be related to the JavaScript Library Version.

**Client Version**

An issue with the Client Version results in a HTTP 403 Forbidden error when trying to load the JavaScript Library.

The client version refers to the version of the JavaScript Library you like to use, for the versions of the JavaScript Library see: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/release-notes-for-javascript-library.html